# rewrite Wordpress subdomain with nginx and htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, nginx

I got a domain ihakula.com, and I want to use blog.ihakula.com to point to my blog with wordpress.

And the path for wordpress is www.ihakula.com:9000/blog/, but I want in address bar which looks like no1.ihakula.com.

Now I use Nginx and .htaccess to made it, seems I got problems.

Here is the Nginx code:

```
# For ihakula blog
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name no1.ihakula.com;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://www.ihakula.com:9000/blog/;
        }
    }
```

Here is the htaccess code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.ihakula\.com\:9000\/blog\/$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/no1\.ihakula\.com\/" [P,L]
</IfModule>
```

Now I removed .htaccess file and changed the wordpress general config looks like this:
[image]

I can reach my wordpress console start with no1.ihakula.com/wp-admin. But when I hover any Post, the link shows below still start with www.ihakula.com:9000 looks like below:
[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly are the problems you encountered? And I don't think you need to touch .htaccess: try changing Site Address (URL) in your WordPress's admin general settings page to http://no1.ihakula.com.

Comment: with "http://".

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just remove .htaccess file and changed the BLOG URL to http://no1.ihakula.com, which works well for no1.ihakula.com/wp-admin. But when I click any post, it still start with www.ihakula.com:9000

Comment: When I changed the Site Address to no1.ihakula.com and when I type it in address bar, which will redirect to www.ihakula.com/zm-blog/ automatically and which shows not found.

Comment: I said change the Site Address (站点地址), not the WordPress Address (URL). WordPress Address is the path to your blog locally, while Site Address is facing the outside world.

Comment: Finally, i use docker solved the subdomain issue.

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not need to do anything in your htaccess file. NGINX proxy can handle the request URL change automatically. What you are doing is actually making the sites to undertake infinite redirects.

What you should do more is to set the `BLOG URL` in WordPress to `no1.ihakula.com`, so that WordPress scripts will automatically give the URLs begins with `no1.ihakula.com`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just remove .htaccess file and changed the BLOG URL to http://no1.ihakula.com, which works well for no1.ihakula.com/wp-admin. But when I click any post, it still start with www.ihakula.com:9000

Comment: @ihakula.com do you have cache or something? or you haven't change all the link to take effect?

Comment: I think it take effects. and I set Wordpress URL to : http://no1.ihakula.com and set Site URL to : http://www.ihakula.com:9000/zm-blog. But when I change Site URL to http://no1.ihakula.com too and no1.ihakula.com will redirected to www.ihakula.com/zm-blog NOT FOUND

Comment: I don't think you have fully updated the WordPress URL. You should check whether your BLOG URL has been updated fully. Open your database controller, find the table wp_options. Find the columns with option_name named site url and home, change the option_value to the corresponding URL in your local environment.

Comment: Try the opposite combination Site URL to : http:// no1.ihakula.com and set Wordpress URL to : http:// ihakula.com:9000/zm-blog?